# Android ListView listSelector not working

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to set a custom selector to a ListView. It's working fine on newer devices but not working on lower version of devices.I want the ListView selected item to be stay highlighted.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

**ListView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewBell"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#b5b5b5"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_color" >

            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

**list_selectror_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="@color/list_selector" />

        <stroke
            android:dashWidth="2dp"
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/white" />

    </shape>
```

I have also tried with selector but nothing happens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_color" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_normal"/>

</selector>
```

Here is my Custom adapter getView Method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_bell_items, parent,
                false);

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_bell_image);
        imageview.setImageResource(mDataImage[position]);

        TextView textview = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_bell_title);
        textview.setText(mDataText[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you must give selectors for list , the above one is just color shape...

Comment: change `android:listSelector` to `android:background` and test again

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan its just a color code

Comment: list_selectror_color.xml is not a selector, it is a shape

Comment: @pskink I have posted the selectors.kindly take a look

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan android:background  is changing the whole listView not the items.

Comment: what is your adapter? did you write custom adapter ?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan yes I have used custom adapter.

Comment: copy the default selector res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml to your res/drawable and modify it as you want

Comment: so add that line to your list Row of your adapter, if don't get me post getView() method, i will help you.

Comment: @pskink the link is not opening

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan i have posted the getView method

Comment: add `android:background = "@drawable/list_selector_color"` to `listview_bell_items` layout

Comment: @pskink can I use the shape as a drawable?

Comment: @KousiK you can use any drawable you like

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan if I use android:background = "@drawable/list_selector_color" to listview_bell_items.it is showing the color as default but I want when selected.

Comment: what is your mean? this must be `list_selector_normal` in defaul, i don't get you

Comment: @pskink its not staying highlighted,just showing the drawable and going back to default.

Comment: going back to default? after what? some time? your finger interaction?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan it has worked on 4.2 but in 2.2 its the same problem

Comment: @pskink after releasing my finger.I want the item stays selected until I select another item.

Comment: @KousiK this is how it should work, see http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2008/12/touch-mode.html?m=1

Comment: @pskink according to the doc I have already add android:choiceMode="singleChoice" and setSelected(true).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had similar problem. Sorry, cannot comment, so I post a possible answer.

1. Remove `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_color"` property from your `ListView` declaration
2. In your `R.layout.listview_bell_items` specify your custom selector for a root layout. E.g., if root layout of your list item is `RelativeLayout`, try:
   `<RelativeLayout ... android:background="@drawable/listitem_selector">...`

The same goes for any other type of Layout.

If this still still does not give you the result you want, provide more details.

**Update**
Ok, if nothing else helps, there's a temporary dirty workaround of your problem. I do not see why it would not work.

Introduce a **selectedPos** variable holding currently selected item.

```
private class MyAdapter extends .../*your base adapter*/ {                
    private static final int NOT_SELECTED = -1;
    private int selectedPos = NOT_SELECTED;

    // if called with the same position multiple lines it works as toggle
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        if (selectedPos == position) {
            selectedPos = NOT_SELECTED;
        } else {
            selectedPos = position;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position == selectedPos) {
            // your color for selected item
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        } else {
            // your color for non-selected item
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Now, add the following code after you create and set `ListView`'s adapter:

```
final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(...);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        adapter.setSelection(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide details: what do you consider "lower version"? Do you test this thing on emulator?

Comment: ya actually I don't have lower version device,that's why i had to test it using emulator,but in 4.2 real device its working fine.

Comment: Ok, it seems like the behaviour is slightly different in emulator. Forget about step 1 I mentioned: add your selector **both** to your ListView `listSelector` property, and to your list item layout root

Comment: **and** add `android:clickable="true"` property to your root layout

Comment: i have checked it in real device which id 2.3.3 but still the result is same.

Comment: Ok, I think I have working solution for you. Please check my edited answer

Comment: Hi @Drew, thanks for this! however, there is a slight delay when clicking on other items.

Answer (score 2):

That is what I found out:

To get the list selector working the are two approaches:

1)
You use the OnItemClickListener.
Then the list selector drawable/color will work as expected when set it on the list view.
Then you may use a TouchListener for getting ClickEvents of any child view instead of using a ClickListener.

2) 
You have set ClickListener on any child of the row view.
In this case the list selector will not work when been set on the list view, so you have to set your list selector drawable/color as background of the row view.