# ListView: Why doesn't the background change the first time?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I need a way to change the background color of selected items. The code below change the background color ( blue ) only when I click an item for the second time. So when I click an item the first time, it doesn't work.

```
final SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(getApplicationContext(), songList);
lv.setAdapter(songAdt);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(TAG, " executed");
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
);
```

I have just checked ( by using the Log.i function ) that the code is executed 2 times, but only the second time the background is changed. Why ?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question by providing the entire code to the listview?

Comment: Most probably the view does not redraw. Having the full source code would help to see why this happens.

Comment: I have added some code in the above question, what part do you need exactly ? Thanks :)

Comment: @jackgu1988 I have added more code above :)

Comment: @OBX I have added more code above :)

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to highlight the selected item. Please correct me if I'm wrong. You can do that by `lv.setSelector(SOME_DRAWABLE_RESOURCE);`, where SOME_DRAWABLE_RESOURCE can be a colour that you define in `res/values/colors.xml` in the form `R.color.some_colour`

Comment: did your `Log.i(TAG, " executed");` called during first click?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 yes, it's called during the first click

Comment: @jackgu1988 Yes I want to highlight the selected item. I have just tryed lv.setSelector(R.color.activated_color); and it does work BUT it's highlighted even if the item is focused without selecting it ( for example if I put my finger on an item and then scroll ).

Comment: I just noticed that I also have `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` on the container (RelativeLayout in my case) XML file for the item layout (defined in the adapter). Please try a combination of this and my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
private int prevPosition=-1;
```

and your `onItemClick` use:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (i == position) {   

                if(position!=prevPosition){
                   //set your selected color                    
                   adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    prevPosition=position;

                }else{
                    adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    prevPosition=-1;
                   }

               }else{
                  //set your normal color   
                  adapter.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

               }

            }
    }

});
```

**Option 2**

you can use drawable selector for your `listview`

in `res/drawable` folder

background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#000000"/>  // set your selected color   
<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
</shape>
```

normal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    

<padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Now use it in your `listview` in xml:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/background"
```

Comment: This might not be efficient for a music player. It will slow things down in big song lists.

Comment: the edit looks fine and something similar has worked for me in the past. However I am not sure if it will work, as the OP said that this didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936272/how-to-highlight-pressed-items-in-a-listview

Comment: it works ..for me....try it and remove your `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`  `view.setSelected(true);` in onItemClick

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I have just tryed the method 2 and it doesn't work. Could you tell me why ?

Comment: during first click or second click it did not change background?

Comment: if u are using a custom layout for your listview item your should use  `android:background="@drawable/background"` for the root layout ..instead of `android:listSelector="@drawable/background"`

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 it doesn't change during first, second, third, ... click. I have used android:background and android:listSelector. Seems absurd: it's so difficult to just change the background D:

Comment: Maybe because I am using Targed Sdk version 22 ?

Comment: no it should work in sdk 22 also,,see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422196/android-listview-listselector-not-working...you have to add your background drawable for adapter class layout

Answer (score 0):

In listview, we have property  android:listSelector="@color/sky" use this in xml.This will change selected item background.Hope this works for you.

Comment: I have tryed it as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936272/how-to-highlight-pressed-items-in-a-listview
But it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: android:choiceMode="singleChoice" try this in your listview @xRobot

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Line

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

and add this line and see if working

```
parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.list_blue_colour));
```

i have not tested it yet, please share if working, if not working then follow this answer   [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978159/6478047)

Comment: it say that the getColor is deprecated

Comment: try using `setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);` instead and see